# Get custom attachment metabox image Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have added my custom field to the attachments image metabox.

```
function be_attachment_field_credit( $form_fields, $post ) {

    $form_fields['img-page-url'] = array(
        'label' => 'Link to page',
        'input' => 'text',
        'value' => get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'img-page-url', true ),
    );

    return $form_fields;
}
add_filter( 'attachment_fields_to_edit', 'be_attachment_field_credit', 10, 2 );

function be_attachment_field_credit_save( $post, $attachment ) {
    if( isset( $attachment['img-page-url'] ) )
        update_post_meta( $post['ID'], 'img-page-url', $attachment['img-page-url'] );

    return $post;
}
```

How can i use this attachment and output it on a page ?

Comment: grammar, better sentences

Answer (score 0):

So, i guess that you need to get that attachment, and you have only one key ID, that is the post ID.
If it is so, then you need to do these steps:

1. img-page-url meta of the given post.
2. finding corresponding attachment by this meta (because they have common meta)
3. getting an attachment by the given ID.

Let's code it:

```
<?php 
 $common_meta=get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'img-page-url', true );
 global $wpdb;
 $attachment_id=$wbdp->get_var("select post_id from $wpdb->post_meta where meta_key='img-page-url' and meta_value='".esc_sql($common_meta)."' and post_id!=".$post->ID);
 echo wp_get_attachment_image($attachment_id);
```